# Obj-C, zombies memory leak, I can't see it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I think I've got a memory leak, I've enabled zombies and in profiler it highlighted this section of code, I've marked the percentages.

It looks fine to me.

Any ideas ?

```
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) 
              toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        for (DBMetadata *file in [metadata.contents reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
            [tmpArray addObject:file.filename];  -- 44%
        }
    }

    self.itemArray = tmpArray;
    [tmpArray release];

    [self.dropboxTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] 
             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; -- 55.6%

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

EDIT

In the interface :-

```
NSMutableArray *itemArray;
```

Comment: Zombies isn't for detecting leaks; they're for telling you if you attempt to access objects that were dealloc'd.
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Comment: What profiler are you using? Memory or CPU? Are those allocation percentages, or leak percentages?

Comment: When you say 'profiler', do you mean the memory leaks tool?
It's not always straightforward to read the output of the tool, because often it will show you the location where you allocated memory, not the location in the code that was responsible for causing a leak.
Hence, a screenshot of the mem leaks tool might be handy. But generally, I'd look at the items all over the code that are earmarked in the % code above. For example, your tmpArray is set into self.itemArray -- so is something leaking self.itemArray elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the thread generate leaks here if you do not use NSAutoreleasePool?

```
-(void)threadStartAnimating
{
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        //your code.
        [pool release];
}
```

thanks.